# GWT Modal Dialog with Flip animation (like effect library)

Tags: css, gwt

I need to create a modal dialog which filps vertically or horizontally.

I found the effect library, which is nice, but how to integrate it in the GWT.

I added the js file into GWT's HTML file and the style is defined in Dialog box. But I don't see any effect in it.

How to apply the flip effect in the dialog box or is there any other way to achieve this.

popuppanel:

```
<g:PopupPanel ui:field="container" height="300px" width="500px"
        autoHideEnabled="true" glassEnabled="true" styleName="{style.gwtDialogBox}">
        <g:HTMLPanel width="595px" height="297px">
            <g:FlowPanel>
                <g:Image url="images/close.ico" styleName="{style.right}" />
            </g:FlowPanel>
        </g:HTMLPanel>
    </g:PopupPanel>
```

js function in js file.

```
var ModalEffects = (function() {

    function init() {


        [].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll( '.md-trigger' ) ).forEach( function( el, i ) {

            var modal = document.querySelector( '#' + el.getAttribute( 'data-modal' ) ),
                close = modal.querySelector( '.md-close' );

            function removeModal( hasPerspective ) {
                classie.remove( modal, 'md-show' );

                if( hasPerspective ) {
                    classie.remove( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                }
            }

            function removeModalHandler() {
                removeModal( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ); 
            }

            el.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                classie.add( modal, 'md-show' );
                overlay.removeEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );
                overlay.addEventListener( 'click', removeModalHandler );

                if( classie.has( el, 'md-setperspective' ) ) {
                    setTimeout( function() {
                        classie.add( document.documentElement, 'md-perspective' );
                    }, 25 );
                }
            });

            close.addEventListener( 'click', function( ev ) {
                ev.stopPropagation();
                removeModalHandler();
            });

        } );

    }

    init();

})();
```

this is from the effect library.

Thanks,
Bennet.

Comment: please provide the library/your code or something to suggest an answer

Comment: I need something like this http://tympanus.net/Development/ModalWindowEffects/. Here they kept all the element in page and they operate. But in GWT the dialog is getting created after the user click the button. how can I apply the third party js function into my popup panel. please find the code above.

Answer (score 0):

Put your .js  in a public folder, the folder is placed next to a client folder in the same package where your gwt.xml file is located.

Some thing like this

```
-ProjectName
  - src
    - com.myProj
      - public
        -js
           yourJS.js
      *.gwt.xml
```

Also place this in your gwt.xml

```
<script src="_js-url_"/>
```

Compile and try. Also see this for reference [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules)

Comment: I have done this. there is no problem with loading the js file. problem occurs while the dialog is loading. Its not calling the methods in js file.